# UWP DeploymentOptions.ForceApplicationShutdown is not working on all devices

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP app (that is sideloaded) and I am updating the app from a App Service when a new version is found.

I am calling the following line of code:

```
await pm.UpdatePackageAsync(uri, dpdys, DeploymentOptions.ForceApplicationShutdown);
```

It updates the package fine but on some devices the app does not restart.

Why would this behavior occur? What would be different of some devices that would not allow the app to restart?

Comment: Does it throw any exception? What is the result of the IAsyncOperationWithProgress<TResult, TProgress>?

Comment: No Exception is thrown and the results have no ErrorText or ExtendedErrorCode. One thing we found was some devices are running the Anniversary Edition and other are the one version behind.